# How can an Image crop, resize be expressed as an affine transformation?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, affinetransform

I've got an image that gets cropped and resized to the image input size. 
To my understanding this is the same as an affine transformation.

I am trying to simplify the code below so it does the same by using the function: (something like the example below at the end).

```
scipy.ndimage.affine_transform()
```

The trouble is I don't really understand the parameters of that function, hence I am not able to achieve an elegant one-liner with the affine_transform() function.
Providing and explaining the solution for the code might help me to better understand this affine_transform() function.

```
import numpy as npy
import PIL.Image
import scipy.misc as smc
import scipy.ndimage as snd

#crop factor
s = 1.045    

#input image
img2crop = npy.float32(PIL.Image.open("input_image.jpg)")
h, w = img2crop.shape[:2]    #get the dimensions of the input image

#Box-crop values: calculate new crop Dimensions based on 's'
wcrop =  float(w) / (s)
hcrop =  float(wcrop) / (float(w) / float(h))
hcrop = int(round(hcrop))
wcrop = int(round(wcrop))

#crop applied from top-left to right and bottom
b_left = 0
b_top = 0
b_width = wcrop
b_height = hcrop
b_box = (b_left, b_top, b_width, b_height)

#cropped region
region = img2crop.crop(b_box)

#resize cropped region back to input size
resized_region = smc.imresize(region, (h, w), interp='nearest', mode=None)
#save cropped and resized region as new file in output folder
PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(resized_newregion)).save("output_image.jpg")
```

Question:
How can the code above doing a crop and resize be expressed as an affine transformation?

This example crops evenly on all 4 sides, center oriented

```
s = 0.0065
cropped_and_resized_image = snd.affine_transform(input_image.jpg, [1-s,1-s,1], [h*s/2,w*s/2,0], order=1)
PIL.Image.fromarray(npy.uint8(cropped_and_resized_image)).save("output_image_at.jpg")
```

Thanks in advance for feedback.

Comment: Mathematically, cropping isn't an affine transform, although if you consider affine transformations "onto a canvas" of a given size, then any crop can be considered a combination of the destination canvas size and possibly a translation. Resizing is simply scaling, which is an affine transform.

Comment: You're right; cropping isn't an affine transformation. Shall I rephrase the question? Still, can this code above be trans-coded as an affine_transform function. I hope (and believe) it can. But how?

Comment: It appears to me that this is not possible. Applying a crop and resize to the images works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is OpenCV implementation

```
# OpenCV implementation of crop/resize using affine transform

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import cv2

src_rgb = cv2.imread('test_img.jpg')

# Source width and height in pixels
src_w_px = 640 
src_h_px = 480 

# Target width and height in pixels
res_w_px = 640
res_h_px = 480

# Scaling parameter
s = 2.0

Affine_Mat_w = [s, 0, res_w_px/2.0 - s*src_w_px/2.0]
Affine_Mat_h = [0, s, res_h_px/2.0 - s*src_h_px/2.0]

M = np.c_[ Affine_Mat_w, Affine_Mat_h].T 
res = cv2.warpAffine(src_rgb, M, (res_w_px, res_h_px))

# Showing the result
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.subplot(121); plt.imshow(src_rgb); plt.title('Original image');
plt.subplot(122); plt.imshow(res); plt.title('Image warped Affine transform');
```

Answer (score 0):

### OpenCV implementation of crop image && resize to (des_width, des_height) using affine transform

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


def crop_resized_with_affine_transform(img_path, roi_xyxy, des_width, des_height):
    src_rgb = cv2.imread(img_path)

    '''
    image roi 
    (x0,y0)------------(x1,y1)
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
       |                  |
    (-,-)------------(x2, y2)
    '''
    src_points = [[roi_xyxy[0], roi_xyxy[1]], [roi_xyxy[2], roi_xyxy[1]], [roi_xyxy[2], roi_xyxy[3]]]
    src_points = np.array(src_points, dtype=np.float32)
                  
    des_points = [[0, 0], [des_width, 0], [des_width, des_height]]
    des_points = np.array(des_points, dtype=np.float32)

    M = cv2.getAffineTransform(src_points, des_points)
    crop_and_resized_with_affine_transform = cv2.warpAffine(src_rgb, M, (des_width, des_height))

    return crop_and_resized_with_affine_transform
    
    
def crop_resized(img_path, roi_xyxy, des_width, des_height):
    src_rgb = cv2.imread(img_path)    
    roi_img = src_rgb[roi_xyxy[1]:roi_xyxy[3], roi_xyxy[0]:roi_xyxy[2]]
    resized_roi_img = cv2.resize(roi_img, (des_width, des_height))
    
    return resized_roi_img

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    '''
    Source image from 
    https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/P20210303AS-1901.jpg
    or
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Biden#/media/File:Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait.jpg
    '''
    img_path = "Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait.jpg"
    # xmin ymin xmax ymax
    roi_xyxy = [745, 265, 1675, 1520]
    des_width = 480
    des_height = 720
    crop_and_resized_with_affine_transform = crop_resized_with_affine_transform(img_path, roi_xyxy , des_width, des_height)
    resized_roi_img = crop_resized(img_path, roi_xyxy, des_width, des_height)
    cv2.imshow("crop_and_resized_with_affine_transform", crop_and_resized_with_affine_transform)
    cv2.imwrite("crop_and_resized_with_affine_transform.jpg", crop_and_resized_with_affine_transform)
    cv2.imshow("resized_roi_img", resized_roi_img)
    cv2.imwrite("resized_roi_img.jpg", resized_roi_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

### Source image is [Wiki:Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait.jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Biden#/media/File:Joe_Biden_presidential_portrait.jpg)